# How does the Transformation of an Operator Change a function of that Operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

What I often encounter in books, is the following:

Say I have an operator $\hat{o}$, which I want to transform to $\hat{o}'= \hat{M}^{-1} \hat{o}  \hat{M}$. 
When I now consider a "function" $f(\hat{o})$, its transformation is usualy expressed as $f(\hat{o}') = \hat{M}^{-1} f(\hat{o}) \hat{M}$.

My Question: Why can I express it that way? I'd have to make the critical assumption that I can express $f(\hat{o})$ as a sum of products of $\hat{o}$, which means that I can expand $f$ as a taylor series. Is that true?

Edit : I know how to solve this, if f is expandable. The question is, does the equation only hold for f being expandable? I'm thinkin for for example about the Potential operator in the hydrogen atom, which contains a singularity, and cearly isn'texpandable. Is it sufficient that it is expandable nearly everywhere?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: It probably would. I might consider reposting it there.

Comment: Or perhaps migrate? If you crosspost, be sure to mention it on both sites.

Comment: I will consider this the better option.

Comment: Indeed, implicitly, all QM operators are construed as realized by some type of extended [Sylvester's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_formula).

Comment: ... in which case they are linear functions of their Frobenius covariants which transform like the original operator!

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume as we always do in physics that your function $f(o)$ admits a taylor expansion in powers of $o$. Now $f(o')  = f(M^{-1} o M)$ by definition of $o'$.

Expanding this using the taylor series for $f(o)$ it's easy to see that at the nth term is proportional to $M^{-1}o_1MM^{-1}o_2..........MM^{-1}o_{n}M$.

But $MM^{-1} = M^{-1}M = I$

Thus this nth term collapses to 
$M^{-1}o_{1}o_{2}.....o_nM$.

Using linearity of the operators $M$ and $M^{-1}$, you can pull $M^{-1}$ out from every term in the series on the left and $M$ out from every term in the series on the right, such that

$f(o')  = f(M^{-1} o M) = M^{-1}f(o)M$.

QED

Comment: I think the question was precisely about whether or not the assumption of Taylor expansion is necessary, since defining functions of operators works for any measurable function by Borel functional calculus.

Comment: @ACuriousMind yes, that is the Problem.

Comment: I think that @ACuriousMind means is that you can diagonalize the operator as $0=\sum_n\lambda_n P_n$ (the sum can be replaced by  integral) whe there is a continuous spectrum)  where the the $P_n$ are projection operators, and define $f(O)= \sum_n f(\lambda_n) P_n$. No Taylor series is required.